# No light detected from 1310 nm IR optical transceiver AFBR-5813TQZ

Tags: infrared, transceiver, lvds, optical

I am trying to build a test application circuit for an [AFBR-5813TQZ IR (1300 nm) optical transceiver](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AFBR-58x3xxZ-125-Mbaud-Fast-Ethernet-Transceiver-DS). For now, I am only trying to verify that the transmitter works, so I have breadboarded the recommended application circuit from the datasheet, fed 3.3V into Vcc from one power supply, and fed 1V across TD+ and TD- from another power supply with separate grounding via a twisted cable (LVDS). The voltage values were obtained from the recommended operating conditions section of the datasheet.

I am detecting light power output with a lab bench power meter and a short plastic optical fiber cable. However, I do not detect anything when the circuit is powered. I am reasonably sure that the detector and connecting fiber is not at fault because I successfully detect the output of a similar setup with a [AFBR-5972EZ (650 nm) optical transceiver](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AV02-4953EN) and the appropriate settings.

I have verified and remade my breadboard circuit connections multiple times now, so I am reasonably sure I have built the recommended application circuit as specified. Probing the pins of the transceiver also yields voltages I would expect, about 3.3V on Vcc, +0.5V on TD+, and -0.5V on TD-, with respect to the ground of the Vcc power supply. I have multiple copies of the transceiver component as well, so I do not think it is a faulty component causing the issue.

I have frankly never used optical transceivers before, so I am not sure how to proceed. Unfortunately, I do not have another IR source at my disposal to test the detector. I would appreciate any suggestions or advice and can provide more information on my setup if requested. Thanks!

EDIT:
I am editing my post to provide more information on my light detection. I am using a [1936-R Newport Optical Power Meter](https://www.newport.com/p/1936-R). I used a [400-1100 nm detector](https://www.newport.com/p/918D-SL-OD1R) to detect the 650 nm light and a [780-1800 nm detector](https://www.newport.com/p/918D-IR-OD3R) to detect the IR light. For both optical connections, I use the same [1m optical patch cable from Fibertronics](https://fibertronics.com/1m-st-to-st-duplex-multimode-625-fiber-optic-patch-cable). From the [datasheet](https://fibertronics.com/images/uploaded/single-mode-patch-cables-datasheet.pdf), it uses Corning SMF28 fiber, which [seems to be rated for IR wavelengths](https://www.corning.com/media/worldwide/coc/documents/Fiber/SMF-28%20ULL.pdf).

Comment: Hi @GrahamNye! Thank you for your response and good observation. I have edited my post to clarify. I am using two separate detectors for the two wavelengths but the same optical fiber. As far as I can tell from my searches, the cable I am using is rated for IR wavelengths, but this is all very new to me and I would happily stand corrected. I have linked the cable's datasheet and my equipment in the post.

Comment: Rather than passing in a static 1V (which may be filtered away), what happens if you feed an actual LVDS signal, or at least a reasonable approximation of one from a two channels function generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to EE.SE.

You've given us specifications for three different types of fibre optic cable; only one of which is likely to work properly.

In the body of your question you mention plastic fibre. This will generally only work at visible wavelengths ([1](https://www.thefoa.org/tech/wavelength.htm), [2](https://www.lumitex.com/blog/optical-fiber-technology), [3](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/physics-and-astronomy/plastic-fiber)) so will be no good at 1310 nm.

You also mention Corning [SMF-28 optical fibre](https://www.corning.com/media/worldwide/coc/documents/Fiber/SMF-28%20ULL.pdf). This is single mode fibre with a core diameter of 9 μm at 1310 nm λ. Your Broadcom transceiver is intended to work with 50-μm or 62.5-μm core multimode fiber so you'll only couple a small amount of light into a single core fibre. However your detector seems sensitive enough to cope with this (sensitivity of 5 nW or -53 dBm).

The patch cord you linked to, item no: PC-SS6D30V01M, has a data sheet that covers a whole range of different cable types. If you actually have the Corning InfiniCor OM1 62.5/125μm multimode fibre corresponding to that item number it should be fine for 1310 nm.

So what cable do you actually have? Is there a type number printed on the fibre jacket that you can check? If not you might be better off getting a glass fibre patch cord with the correct wavelength range.

Also note the warning in the [datasheet](https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/AFBR-58x3xxZ-125-Mbaud-Fast-Ethernet-Transceiver-DS) of your IR transceiver that:

```
The input of the transmitter sections is internally
AC-coupled and terminated. If a DC signal is received, there
is no light output.
```

You'll need to provide a data signal (or a pulse train looking sufficiently like a data signal) to get any IR light out of your transceiver. I note you've been able to get the visible light transceiver to work. However this has a different pinout and signals so making this work doesn't necessarily mean the IR version will work with your supporting circuitry.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply, I was sick for the past week. Thank you for the comprehensive answer.

I was actually mistaken in my original post. The fiber optic cable I am using is hard clad silica (glass), so it is suitable for IR wavelengths. The jacket of the cable reads, "Plus Corning MMF-62.5/125 optical fiber OFNR(UL) E225130 11/2016 02996M. I have since used it with a different IR source and confirmed it is not the issue.

I think you are most likely correct regarding the data input. I only had access to DC power supplies, but I will be trying again soon with a function generator.